# HitTest region around a PathGeometry

Tags: wpf, pathgeometry

I draw curves on a canvas using wpf `PathGeometry`'s, directly via `DrawingContext`.

The `HitTestResultBehavior` shows that the bounding box of the curve is the whole rectangle enclosing the curve, i.e. TL, TR, BL, BR.

I am considering cutting the curve in smaller parts, drawing them seperately, so that the HitTest region around the curve becomes more fitting to the form of the curve itself.

Is there perhaps a general approach to this problem that you know of?